# TFS string field with auto-completion

Tags: tfs, autocomplete

The "tags" field in TFS has an auto-completion capabilities. 
Is it possible to add a user-define field in TFS that will behave like the "tags" field (e.g. have auto-completion list)? If so, how is it done?

There is an auto-completion for fields with pre-defined value list; I am looking for auto-completion for free-text field, so that users can see if someone else used a very-similar string as they are about to enter and choose it. This re-use of  existing values reduces the accumulation of slightly-different values that basically say the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you have pointed out in the updated question. You can enumerate a set of values for a field by defining a pick list as part of its definition or at some point during the workflow. **You can specify that the list can contain only allowed values, cannot contain prohibited values, or can suggest values.** If you suggest values, users can specify a value other those in the pick list.

You use `SUGGESTEDVALUES` to define a list of values that a field can contain. Users can specify other values in addition to those that you suggest.

```
<SUGGESTEDVALUES for="userGroupName" not="userGroupName" expanditems="true | false" filteritems="excludegroups">  
      <GLOBALLIST name="globalListName" />  
      <LISTITEM value="Name1" />  
      <LISTITEM value="Name2" />  
      <LISTITEM value="Name3" />  
. . .   
</SUGGESTEDVALUES>
```

You can also define dependent pick lists, in which you define two or more lists for a field but only one list appears at run time based on the evaluation of a conditional rule.

More details please take a look at this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-pick-lists?view=azure-devops).

---

However, what you are looking for the auto-completion is kind of search feature (ex: google)

[image]

This is **not supported** at present. It's not available to do this in TFS now.